NextJS + Wallet-Core, can not initWasm
I want to integrate my NextJS project with TrustWallet, after install @trustwallet/wallet-core through npm, I start to learn with example:
useEffect(() => {
import { initWasm } from "@trustwallet/wallet-core";
    
initWasm().then((WalletCore) => {
      const { CoinType, HexCoding, HDWallet,
        AnyAddress, Derivation, DerivationPath } = WalletCore;
      const mnemonic = "abandon ability able about above absent absorb abstract absurd abuse access accident";
      const wallet = HDWallet.createWithMnemonic(mnemonic, "")
      const address = wallet.getAddressForCoin(CoinType.bitcoin)
      console.log("Bitcoin Address:", address)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('initWasp error', error)
    })
  }, [])

But after run, I saw this error:
initWasp error RuntimeError: Aborted(both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed)
    at n (wallet-core.js:37:429)
    at Ua (wallet-core.js:39:149)
    at eval (wallet-core.js:40:238)

wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': HTTP status code is not ok


Can someone guide me how to solved this, I read about TrustWallet then saw it's does not support NodeJS server project, so I change to use it on my NextJS
